# How to setup Styled-Components "Base Icon Styles"

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components icons library and they have a particular feature for setting up styles across all the icons. I'm trying to use it, but they have barely any documentation on the tool and I can't figure out how it's supposed to be used.

source: https://github.com/styled-icons/styled-icons

example they provide:

```js
// If you wish to style all icons at once, you can create a wrapper styled component 
// that imparts a particular style to all icons contained within the wrapper 
// by targeting the StyledIconBase component:

import styled from 'styled-components'
import {StyledIconBase} from '@styled-icons/styled-icon'

export const IconStyleWrapper = styled.div`
  ${StyledIconBase} {
    color: red;
    /* icon styles go here */
  }
`
```

What my IconHandler component currently looks like:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Youtube } from '@styled-icons/fa-brands';
import { StyledIconBase } from '@styled-icons/styled-icon';

interface IBrandIcon {
  brand: 'youtube';
  size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
}

const BrandIcon = ({ brand, size }: IBrandIcon): JSX.Element => {
  switch (brand) {
    case 'youtube':
      return (
        <IconStyleWrapper>
          <YoutubeIcon />
        </IconStyleWrapper>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <IconStyleWrapper>
          <YoutubeIcon />
        </IconStyleWrapper>
      );
  }
};

export default BrandIcon;

const YoutubeIcon = styled(Youtube)<{ size: IBrandIcon['size'] }>`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.agnosticStyles.brands.youtube};
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
`;

export const IconStyleWrapper = styled.div`
  ${StyledIconBase} {
    color: green;
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    /* icon styles go here */
    ${YoutubeIcon} {
      color: orange;
    }
  }

  ${YoutubeIcon} {
    color: orange;
  }
`;
```

If I dont wrap the `YoutubeIcon` with `IconStyleWrapper` it returns as expected, pretty normal. However, nothing appears at all when I wrap it with the Wrapper. I don't know what they're getting at with their documentation, but I could really use a single entry point to establish the base styles for icons and I can't figure out what this needs.

Comment: If you inspect the element that you're trying to style, does the styling in the IconStyleWrapper show up on the inspector? Have you tried adding the `!important` flag to the StyledIconBase component styling.